# Access C# Enums and Classes from other namespaces in IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, enums, namespaces, ironpython

I am stuck on what I would think should be a rather basic feature of IronPython integration with C# (this is, of course, a very simplified example). Below is a simple multi-project solution. The first project defines an enum and a class from one namespace

```cs
namespace EnumTest
{
    public class EnumTest
    {
        public enum FooEnum
        {
            FooOne = 101,
            FooTwo = 102,
        };

        public EnumTest(FooEnum f)
        {
            _f = f;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have another project which encompasses all of IronPython: the runtime DLLs, the Python modules, and the C# class that runs the python script from a file.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace IronPythonRunner
{
    public class IronPythonRunner
    {
        public IronPythonRunner()
        {
            ScriptEngine ironPythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
            ScriptScope pythonScope = ironPythonEngine.CreateScope();
            dynamic scope = pythonScope;

            const string script = "c:/temp/try.py";
            String scriptDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(script);
            String ironPyDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\IronPythonDistributable\\Lib";
            ICollection<String> paths = ironPythonEngine.GetSearchPaths();
            paths.Add(scriptDir);
            paths.Add(ironPyDir);
            ironPythonEngine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

            ScriptSource source = ironPythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(script);
            try
            {
                source.Execute(pythonScope);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                ironPythonEngine.Runtime.Shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a c# project that is a test GUI for running a python script

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IronPythonNamespaceTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IronPythonRunner.IronPythonRunner r = new IronPythonRunner.IronPythonRunner();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the following python script

```py
print "hello world"
print str(FooEnum.FooOne)
t = EnumTest(FooEnum.FooTwo)
```

I get the "hello world" output, but then I get a C# IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: name 'FooEnum' is not defined. Which brings me to my question, **how should I be accessing the enum and the class from within my python script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your assembly:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("assembly_name")
from EnumTest import EnumTest
from EnumTest.EnumTest import FooEnum
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe it's almost correct. The "assembly" in this case is actually the assembly name (in my case, it's EnumTest) of the project containing the namespace EnumTest, which in turn contains the EnumTest namespace, which in  turn contains the EnumTest class, which in turn contains FooEnum.

Comment: So how would this extend to a case where the namespace is "foo.bar.baz"  and the enumeration is not actually declared within a class, but public on the namespace level?

Comment: you can use: `from foo.bar.baz import enumName`. Take a look here for more examples: http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html